# How to create convolve function for two matrixes?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to create a convolver function without using the convolve function of    NumPy that get 4 elements:

```
convolver_1(j, matrices_list, filter_matrix, stride_size)
```

The function should return the output after performing a convolution operation with `filter_matrix`, with a stride of size ​`stride_size`, over matrix in index    j at matrices_list, `filter_matrix` has lower dimensions than the matrices in `​matrices_list`.

Comment: Exactly why don't you want to use numpy's convolve function?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you post the code from your current attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through a simple implementation of `np.convolve` whose documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html).

```py
import numpy as np

def convolve_1d(a, filter):
  N, M = len(a), len(filter)
  assert N >= M # assumption in the question
  # in the full mode (default of np.convolve), result length is N+M-1
  # therefore, pad should be M-1 on each side
  # N-M+2p+1 == N+M-1 => p = M-1
  result_length = N+M-1
  result = np.zeros(result_length) # allocating memory for result
  p = M-1
  padded_a = np.pad(a,p)
  flipped_filter = np.flip(filter)
  for i in range(result_length):
    result[i] = np.sum(np.multiply(flipped_filter, padded_a[i:i+M]))
  return result


a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
filter = np.array([1,-1,3])
convolve_1d(a, filter)
```

results in

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  4.,  7.,  5., 12.])
```

which is the same as the result for `np.convolve(a, filter)`.
So, it basically pads the input array with zeros, flips the filter and sums the element-wise multiplication of two arrays.

I am not sure about the index that you mentioned; the result is a 1d array and you can index its elements.

To add stride to this function, we need to modify the `result_length` and multiply the stride to the iterator:

```py
def convolve_1d_strided(a, filter, stride):
  N, M = len(a), len(filter)
  assert N >= M # assumption in the question
  # in the full mode (default of np.convolve), result length is N+M-1
  # therefore, pad should be M-1 on each side
  # N-M+2p+1 == N+M-1 => p = M-1
  result_length = (N+M-1)//stride
  result = np.zeros(result_length) # allocating memory for result
  p = M-1
  padded_a = np.pad(a,p)
  flipped_filter = np.flip(filter)
  for i in range(result_length):
    result[i] = np.sum(np.multiply(flipped_filter, padded_a[i*stride:i*stride+M]))
  return result

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
filter = np.array([1,-1,3])
convolve_1d_strided(a, filter, 2)
```

```
array([1., 4., 5.])
```

Hope it helps and if that is what you liked to see, I am happy to expand it to two dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

For 1D arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


def conv1d(A, kernel, stride, reverse_kernel=True, mode='full'):
    if reverse_kernel:
        kernel = kernel[::-1]

    if mode == 'full':    
        A = np.pad(A, kernel.shape[0] - 1)
    #else: convolution in 'valid' mode

    # Sliding-window view of A
    output_size = (A.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0])//stride + 1
    A_w = as_strided(A, shape=(output_size, kernel.shape[0]), 
                        strides=(stride*A.strides[0], A.strides[0]))

    # Return convolution of A with kernel
    return np.sum(A_w * kernel, axis=1)
```

Here `A = matrices_list[j]`. Note that in Deep Learning the filters in convolution are not reversed.